# sed replace whitespace with underscore between 2 strings

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed

I have a file that contains lines like this

`some thing <phrase>a phrase</phrase> some thing else <phrase>other stuff</phrase>`

I need to replace all the spaces between `<phrase>` tags with an underscore.  So basically I need to replace every space that falls between `>` and `</` with an underscore.  I've tried many different commands in sed, awk, and perl but haven't been able to get anything to work.  Below are some of the commands I've tried.

`sed 's@>\s+[</]@_@g'`

`perl -pe 'sub c{$s=shift;$s=~s/ /_/g;$s}s/>.*?[<\/]/c$&/ge'`

`sed 's@\(\[>^[<\/]]*\)\s+@\1_@g'`

`awk -v RS='\\[>^[<\]/]*\\]' '{ gsub(/\<(\s+)\>/, "_", RT); printf "%s%s", $0, RT }' infile`

I've been looking at these 2 questions trying to modify the answers to use the characters I need.
[sed substitute whitespace for dash only between specific character patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46946593/sed-substitute-whitespace-for-dash-only-between-specific-character-patterns)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63335/how-to-remove-all-white-spaces-just-between-brackets-using-unix-tools

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Do the commands have to be as unreadable as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to replace every space that falls between `>` and `</` with an underscore.

That won't actually do what you want because e.g. in

```
some thing <phrase>a phrase</phrase> some thing else <phrase>other stuff</phrase>
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

the substrings "between `>` and `</`" cover more than you think (marked `^` above).

I think the most straightforward way to express your requirements in Perl is

```
perl -pe 's{>[^<>]*</}{ $& =~ tr/ /_/r }eg'
```

Here `[^<>]` is used to make sure that the matched substring cannot contain `<` or `>` (in particular, it cannot match other `<phrase>` tags).

If that's too readable, you can also do

```
perl '-pes;>[^<>]*</;$&=~y> >_>r;eg'
```

Comment: See https://ideone.com/Oz6ckt. It should be `'s{<phrase>.*?</phrase>}{ $& =~ tr/ /_/r }eg'`. However, strings might have line breaks between tags, in the general case.

Comment: Thank you so much.  For the input I'll be handling there won't be line breaks between tags.

Comment: @melpomene.. I tried something like ````perl -lne ' s/(?=>)([^<>]+?)(?=<\/)/```` but it is not working... could you please help me?.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use regular expressions to parse XML/HTML.

```
use warnings;
use 5.014;  # for /r modifier
use Mojo::DOM;

my $text = <<'ENDTEXT';
some thing <phrase>a phrase</phrase> some thing else <phrase>other stuff</phrase>
ENDTEXT

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new($text);
$dom->find('phrase')->each(sub { $_->content( $_->content=~tr/ /_/r ) });
print $dom;
```

Output:

```
some thing <phrase>a_phrase</phrase> some thing else <phrase>other_stuff</phrase>
```

---

*Update:* [Mojolicious](https://metacpan.org/release/Mojolicious) even contains some sugar that allows smashing that code into a oneliner:

```
$ perl -Mojo -pe '($_=x($_))->find("phrase")->each(sub{$_->content($_->content=~tr/ /_/r)})' input.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought since it had a lot of free text mixed in with tags that a parser wouldn't work

Comment: I was assuming the input file wasn't HTML because OP described it as being line based.

Comment: it is line based, its not an xml/html file

Comment: `Mojo::DOM` is luckily pretty liberal in what it accepts, as the example shows

Comment: @gary69 "free text" is just a text node in XML. It can contain anything, except for XML tags which are separate nodes. Like most HTML/XML parsers, Mojo::DOM allows you to get at the text nodes as well.

Answer (score 1):

Another Perl, replacing between the `<phrase>` tags

```
$ export a="some thing <phrase>a phrase</phrase> some thing else <phrase>other stuff</phrase>"

$ echo $a | perl -lne ' s/(?<=<phrase>)(.+?)(?=<\/phrase>)/$x=$1;$x=~s{ }{_}g;sprintf("%s",$x)/ge ;  print '
some thing <phrase>a_phrase</phrase> some thing else <phrase>other_stuff</phrase>

$
```

**EDIT**

Thanks @haukex, shortening further

```
$ echo $a | perl -lne ' s/(?<=<phrase>)(.+?)(?=<\/phrase>)/$x=$1;$x=~s{ }{_}g;$x/ge ;  print '
some thing <phrase>a_phrase</phrase> some thing else <phrase>other_stuff</phrase>

$
```

Comment: IMHO `s/<phrase>\K(.+?)(?=<\/phrase>)/` would be better, so the `<phrase>` isn't part of the match. Also, what is `sprintf("%s",$x)` for?

Comment: @haukex, yes \K is fine, but ````(?=<phrase>)```` is more readable here.. using sprintf(), you can replace back the matched string (actually $1=$& here)

Comment: @haukex.. btw melphomene has done it cleverly using ````$& =~ tr/ /_/r```` and I like that

Comment: "More readable" is of course a matter of opinion, my point was that it acts differently than `\K` - the equivalent would be `(?<=<phrase>)`. `sprintf("%s",$x)` can be replaced by just `$x`.

Comment: @haukex.. yes you are right. I updated the answer.. and reg sprintf()... I wonder  why I missed.. as I have been lots of %05d replacements in my projects and totally forgot that simple variable would do.. im really stuck!.. thanks for hammering it..

Comment: @haukex.. I think you can help me.. do you know why ````/(?=>)(.*?)(?=<\/)/```` works but not ````(?=>)([^<>]+)(?=<\/)````

Comment: The problem with the second one is again the lookahead instead of a lookbehind. Remember that lookarounds are zero-width, they don't cause the position of the matcher to change. `(?=>)` means "only match here if the next thing is a `>`", i.e. it overlaps with the next part of the match, but then the next thing is `[^<>]`, so the match is always impossible. (This overlap issue is what I meant in my first comment regarding `(?=<phrase>)`.) `(?<=>)` means "only match here if the *previous* thing is `>`", so that lookbehind doesn't overlap with `[^<>]+` and it works.

Comment: @haukex.. thank you for the explanation..now I understand

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/<phrase>|<\/phrase>/\n&/g;ta;:a;s/^([^\n]*(\n[^\n ]*\n[^\n]*)*\n[^\n]*) /\1_/;ta;s/\n//g' file
```

Delimit tags by inserting newlines. Iteratively substitute spaces between pairs of newlines with underscores. When there are no more matches, remove the introduced newlines.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -v RS='</?phrase>' '!(NR%2){gsub(/\s+/,"_")} {ORS=RT}1' file
some thing <phrase>a_phrase</phrase> some thing else <phrase>other_stuff</phrase>
```

Answer (score 1):

if your data in 'd' by gnu sed;

```
sed -E ':b s/<(\w+)>([^<]*)\s([^<]*)(<\/\1)/<\1>\2_\3\4/;tb' d
```